# I want to loop through Woocommerce Product Catogories and show them in dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I want to loop through **Woocommerce Product Catogories** and show them in **dropdown**. I have tried almost every piece of code available on internet but seems that they are not working for me. I'm very new in wordpress. Can anyone help me out? Currently i'm using this code but it's not returning anything.

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
        echo '<br /><a href="' . get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
        ?>
        <?php

        $args2 = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'child_of' => 0,
            'parent' => $category_id,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'show_count' => $show_count,
            'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li' => $title,
            'hide_empty' => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories($args2);
        if ($sub_cats) {
            foreach ($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo $sub_category->name;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show all category under parent
For Example- 
Category 1
   - Subcategory 1
   - Subcategory 2
Category 2
   - Subcategory 3
   - Subcategory 4
Try this code.
We are change parent=0 in get all category.

```
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty,
    'parent' => 0,
);
$all_categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
        echo '<br /><a href="' . get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
        ?>
        <?php

        $args2 = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'child_of' => 0,
            'parent' => $category_id,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'show_count' => $show_count,
            'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li' => $title,
            'hide_empty' => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories($args2);
        if ($sub_cats) {
            foreach ($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo $sub_category->name;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I copied your code in my `<td></td>` but nothing is being shown there.

Comment: For some reason i get empty space.

Comment: Any category print or not. If not any category print then check it any product assing in category or not

Comment: <?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty,
    'parent' => 0,
);
$all_categories = get_categories($args);
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($all_categories);
?>

Comment: I cleared my browser history and it is now working fine for me. :)